# Find all connected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say that I am creating following DB:

Nodes:

`City (id, is_driveable), Highway (id), Road (id), etc.`

Edges:

`Connected_to`

City should be connected to highway (or road or anything else) with another city which could be connected to another city by same or different road etc.

In result I would have `City->[Connected_to]->Highway->[Connected_to]->City->...`

City can be connected to another city by more than one way (imagine 2 parallel highways).

I want to select all Cities that are connected to city with specified ID but also exclude roads for example. Right now I have this query:

```
MATCH path = (city)-[:CONNECTED_WITH*]-(connected_city)
WHERE id(city) = 15 AND ALL(node IN nodes(path) WHERE NOT node:Road)
RETURN city, relationships(path) as r, connected_city
```

This works great if city is connected to another city only by ONE way. Problems start when I have mentioned 2 parallel highways which connect same cities. This query then results in infinite loop (at least I believe). I think that it finds path from first to second city and then goes back to first and so on. I can not limit number of hops to get to target since it can be variable.

Any ideas on how to acomplish this?

Comment: While you won't get infinite loops in Cypher (because the same relationship cannot be traversed more than once per path), you will get paths that revisit previously visited cities when there are multiple relationships to those cities. The number of possible paths in your graph might be incredibly high, so it may not complete. There are ways to get distinct cities during expansion or prevent revisiting nodes using APOC Procedures, but you would either need to remove returning the relationships in your return, or be satisfied that you'll only get one path to each city rather than all paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [APOC Procedures path expanders](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) to get all connected nodes and work around the Cypher limitations that would otherwise cause such queries to spin forever, but there is a drawback. The way such efficiency is achieved is by only visiting each distinct node once by a single distinct path (thus cutting down on the number of paths generated by the query for exploration, and dismissing multiple paths to the same node when they're found), so you won't get all possible paths to all nodes, just one possible path.

If that is acceptable, then you should be able to achieve what you want using APOC path expanders, notably `apoc.path.spanningTree()` (because it returns the path to each node) or `apoc.path.subgraphNodes()` (if you only need connected nodes but not the path to them). We can use the label filter to ensure the paths to the connected nodes don't include :Roads, and always end at :City nodes.

```
MATCH (city)
WHERE id(city) = 15
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(city, {labelFilter:'-Road|>City', relationshipFilter:'CONNECTED_WITH'}) YIELD path
WITH city, path
WHERE length(path) <> 0
RETURN city, relationships(path) as r, last(nodes(path)) as connected_city
```

Comment: I am going to test this because it looks promising. I can easily fetch all paths after I have all nodes retrieved which should be achievable with your query